Using a modern Linux computer as a VT52 Terminal for a CAEN Sy127
I have an old CAEN Sy127 high voltage supply which I would like to control from a modern linux machine. The Manual (p. 20; also there is a more thorough documentation of the communications module in section 2.3 starting on p.9) says that the HV system can be controlled by any VT52-compatible terminal. I have the system connected to the linux PC using a cable with 25-pin RS232 on one end and 9-pin RS232 on the other, going into a Digitus RS232 to USB adapter.
I believe I can emulate a VT52 terminal using xterm -ti vt52 -tn vt52 and then connect the terminal to the device using kermit, but to be honest I do not really know what I am doing (this is my first time using kermit). In kermit I set the baud rate, parity and stop bits according to what is set in the CAEN system. When I try to connect it says carrier required but not detected. with set carrier-watch off it seems to connect but I don't get any response from the device and can't input any characters.
What could be the issue here? Is there maybe something simple that I am missing, since I don't have much experience in this area?
Also please let me know in case there is a better way than using xterm and kermit. I have found people using screen for similar things but it doesn't seem to be working either and I'm not sure if it can emulate VT52.
I originally posted this on the electrical engineering stack exchange but was directed here since my questions are mainly on the software side.
Edit:
I tried using minicom and picocom and neither worked. I took another look at the manual and about the DSR port it says "Ignored if not connected. If connected, must be asserted externally for Data Transmission to proceed" (p. 17) and that xon/xoff is also supported. I tried setting the flow control to xon/xoff in picocom but still got nothing.
The cable I am using has male DB-25 on one end (going into the voltage supply) and female DB-9 on the other. The USB Adapter has male DB-9.
I tested the connections of the cable and on the DB-9 end only pins 2, 3 and 5 are connected, so no DSR. Pin 2 of the DB-9 connector is connected to pin 3 of the DB-25 and vice versa, which should be correct according to my understanding. Pin 5 is ground.

Is the serial port set to the correct bit rate (matching page 22 of the PDF)? Have you tried tools like tio or picocom, which just connect to the serial port without any terminal emulation (letting xterm handle that)? They have keyboard shortcuts to show the serial port control lines (DTR DSR etc), which is how programs detect a 'carrier'.

Yes, the baud rate matches what is set in the communications controller. No I have never heard of those tools, I will try them.

You link to the adaptor mentions voltage levels used by CMOS and TTL. This confuses me, because RS232 voltage levels are quite different.

"I believe I can emulate a VT52 terminal using ..." - Rather than kermit, you should  use a terminal emulation program, such as minicom. Don't bother trying to get xterm to emulate a VT52; let minicom do that. "When I try to connect it says carrier required but not detected." - That reads a lot like the DSR modem control line is expected to be asserted. Minicom can be configured to do that.

"a cable with 25-pin RS232 on one end" - Presumably you mean there's a DB-25 connector. See https://superuser.com/questions/547374/is-db-25-port-serial-or-parallel/547660#547660 From my experience back in the day, serial DB-25 connections were not always plug-n-play because of DCE versus DTE and gender mismatches. If there's no apparent data transfer going on, then verify that the TxD pin on the power supply's serial port is a negative voltage, and is connected to the RxD pin of that USB-to-serial adapter.

@sawdust how can I configure minicom to assert the DSR line or circumvent its use? Also, why should TxD be connected to RxD? The Voltages on both TxD and RxD are both negative, but they are connected to TxD and RxDon the adapter, respectively  (pin 2 on the male DB-9 of the cable is connected to pin 2 on the adapter, and pin 3 is connected to pin 3). (Also see my edit of the question)

Try first without a DSR signal or any flow control.  The PC serial port has a DTE pinout. Your PS has a DCE pinout. So the straight modem cable you have turns out to be the one to use. See http://wilbo666.pbworks.com/w/page/49320712/RS232     I'm used to signal names based on UART pins, so an output needs to be delivered to an input.  But there are some DCE and adapters that label its input as "TxD" and output as "RXD"; apparently such labels refer to the signal names at the other end. Minicom's emulation for VT100 should be a superset of VT52. I revert to using a 'scope when desperate.
